# Does docker EXPOSE refer to the container port or the host port?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, port

The **Dockerfile** command `EXPOSE` and the `docker run` argument `--expose` tells docker that the port must be exposed.

When publishing ports with `-p`, you can map an **outer host port** to a different **inner container port**, e.g. `docker run -p 8080:80`, where `8080` is the **host port** and `80` is the **container port**.

My question is, does `EXPOSE` refer to the inner container port or the outer host port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) instruction in a Dockerfile refers to the container port.

Answer (score 4):

The EXPOSE instruction documents the port on which an application inside the container is expected to be listening. The important word there is "documents". It does not change the behavior of docker running your container, it does not publish the port, and does not impact the ability to connect between containers.

Whether or not you expose the port, you need to separately publish the port to access it from outside the container network. And whether or not you expose the port, you can connect between containers on the same docker network.

There are various tools that can use this image metadata to automatically discover your application. This includes the `-P` flag to publish all container ports on random high numbered host ports. You will also see reverse proxies (like traefik) use this when querying the docker engine to determine the default port to use for your container.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose), the `EXPOSE` instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at **runtime**. So it refers to the inner **container**.

`EXPOSE` allow communication between the container and other containers in the **same network**. But it does not allow communication with the host machine, or containers in another network! In order to permit that, you need to **publish** the port, with `-p` option.

Answer (score 1):

`EXPOSE` just means those exposed ports of this current container are available/exposed to all containers that are in the same network.